# Why does python think I haven't defined my variables?

Tags: python

I wrote a game of Hang-man, to play with the computer. It picks a word from another python file called 'words' and you guess letters. But it doesn't matter where I define my names, it always says they're not defined.

```
>     line 20, in <module>
>     while len(word_letters) > 0: 
> NameError: name 'word_letters' is not defined

>     line 27, in <module>
>     while len(word) > 0:
> NameError: name 'word' is not defined

>     line 31, in <module>
>     while len(alphabet) > 0:
> NameError: name 'alphabet' is not defined
```

I defined my variables in def hangman, so why is it not communicating. Do I need to set it as a global variable somewhere?

```
    import random
from words import words 
import string

def get_valid_word(words):
    word = random.choice(words)     # randomly chooses something from the list
    while '-' in words or ' ' in word:
        word = random.choice(words)

    return word

def hangman():
    word = get_valid_word(words)
    word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letters = set()        # what the user has guessed already

    #getting user input 
    word_letters = set(word)
while len(word_letters) > 0:

    word = random.choice(words)
    word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letters = set()        # what the user has guessed already

    # letters they already used
    # ' '.join (['a', 'b', 'cd']) --> 'a b c d'
    print('You have used these already: ', ' '.join(used_letters))

    # what current word is (ie W - R D)
    word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
    print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))

    user_letter =input('Guess a letter').upper()
    if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
        used_letters.add(user_letter)
        if user_letter in word_letters:
            word_letters.remove(user_letter)

    elif user_letter in used_letters:
        print('You have already used that character. Please try again.')

    else:
        print('You didn\'t type in a valid character. Please try again.')

# gets here when len(word_letters) == 0

user_input = input('Type something:')
print(user_input)
```

Comment: `word_letters` is only defined in the scope of the `hangman` method, so things outside that scope cannot access it.

Comment: Your loop isn't part of the function where the variables are defined. You need to indent it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix indentation on while line 24
and fix variables name should have unique names that don't equal import names

```
    import random
import string

from words import words


def get_valid_word(words_var):
    word = random.choice(words_var)  # randomly chooses something from the list
    while '-' in words_var or ' ' in word:
        word = random.choice(words_var)

    return word


def hangman():
    word = get_valid_word(words)
    word_letters = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letters = set()  # what the user has guessed already

    # getting user input
    word_letters = set(word)

    while len(word_letters) > 0:

        word = random.choice(words)
        word_letters = set(word)
        alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
        used_letters = set()  # what the user has guessed already

        # letters they already used
        # ' '.join (['a', 'b', 'cd']) --> 'a b c d'
        print('You have used these already: ', ' '.join(used_letters))

        # what current word is (ie W - R D)
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letters else '-' for letter in word]
        print('Current word: ', ' '.join(word_list))

        user_letter = input('Guess a letter').upper()
        if user_letter in alphabet - used_letters:
            used_letters.add(user_letter)
            if user_letter in word_letters:
                word_letters.remove(user_letter)

        elif user_letter in used_letters:
            print('You have already used that character. Please try again.')

        else:
            print('You didn\'t type in a valid character. Please try again.')


# gets here when len(word_letters) == 0

user_input = input('Type something:')
print(user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what other have said regarding indentation, I see no calls to the `hangman` function. This means these values are never being initiated to begin with. I would make a call at the end of your program to start the whole process. Something like:

```
    hangman()
    user_input = input('Type something:')
    print(user_input)
```